# C# property name change effects ID in HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

c# code:

```
public class Person{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public age int { get; set; }
}
```

cshtml code which generates an id of #Person_Name

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Person.Name)
```

javascript code:

```
$('#Person_Name').on("change", function () {
//Do something  
}
```

If I change the Person class property name from Name to FullName.  The next step is to modify the cshtml code to read as:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Person.FullName)
```

I understand you can manually go in and change the Jquery code, but if this change is made and the person making the change is unaware of the jquery, it is going to cause an error.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening through some form of notification or logging?  Rather than just remembering that the jquery needs to be changed.

Comment: It's hard to help when we can't see your code.

Comment: *"it won't alert me that my JavaScript is now targeting an id that is non existent."* If you have your developer's tools open in the browser and you are looking at the "Console" tab, you will see your errors. Trying to work with an element that wasn't found will result in an error similar to `Unable to find property Xyz on undefined.`

Answer (score 0):

You do have the option to use:

```
@Html.IdFor(x => x.Person.FullName)
```

Or

```
@Html.NameFor(x => x.Person.FullName)
```

That does rely on having small bits of script in pages, but for what id do this is mostly calling functions in .js resources which from my point of view I find better for reuse anyway.

You may still not get alerted to all issues unless you choose to compile your MVC views, you'll probably get a warning if you have the view open. How you set up your project to compile your MVC views will depend on the type of project but a quick Google should help with that one.